# How to assign a pointer to interface in Go

Tags: go

```
package main

import "fmt"

type intr interface {
    String() string
}

type bar struct{}

func (b *bar) String() string {
    return "bar"
}

type foo struct {
    bar *intr
}

func main() {
    bar1 := bar{}
    foo1 := foo{bar: &bar1} 
    fmt.Println(foo1)
}
```

I get a compile-time error:

> cannot use &bar1 (type *bar) as type *intr in field value: *intr is pointer to interface, not interface

Why is this error happened?
How to assign `foo.bar`?

Answer (score 2):

You're assigning it to a *pointer* to the interface. After changing the field type to interface it will work:

```
type foo struct {
    bar intr
}
```

Pointers to interfaces are quite rarely needed.

Answer (score 2):

[Uber-go style guide pointers-to-interfaces](https://github.com/uber-go/guide/blob/master/style.md#pointers-to-interfaces) contains exact answer to your question,

> You almost never need a pointer to an interface. You should be passing interfaces as values—the underlying data can still be a pointer. An interface is two fields: A pointer to some type-specific information. You can think of this as "type."
>   And a data pointer. If the data stored is a pointer, it’s stored directly. If the data stored is a value, then a pointer to the value is stored.
>   If you want interface methods to modify the underlying data, you must use a pointer.

My recommendation is to get acquainted with it as soon as possible,

Hope it helps